# Does string("abc") return anything?

Tags: c++, return

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    if ( string( "abc" ).size() == 3 )
        cout << "equ." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Does `string("abc")` return anything? If it does, that's a value or a reference?

Comment: it's a temporary object of type string. Also im surprised this compiles since string is not included

Comment: How else do you expect to be able to call size on it?

Comment: It's an anonymous object of type `std::string`.

Comment: It *IS* the constructor.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I do not think this question should be down-voted. `T t;` and `T()` both construct objects. In the first case it is entirely clear where the object is constructed, but in the latter case there are multiple options and I do not think that my beginner's book explained a lot about it.

Comment: @Borgleader It might be included indirectly via `iostream`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class constructors do not have specified return type, and do not have return statement.  But they do have implicit return type - same as class in which they are declared and constructor "returns" just constructed object.

`T()` calls default constructor and "returns" anonymous `prvalue` of type `T` (which binds to `T&&`). Its lifetime is lifetime of expression in which it is used. It is modifiable.

Use example:

```
int()                                           // 0
(string()+=string("123")+="abc").substr(1,3)    // "23a"
```

Comment: It doesn't return `T&&`, it returns `T` but it's an rvalue. If it returned `T&&` then it'll have a dangling reference. You're confusing *types* with *value categories*.

Comment: There's no "return" here at all. `string("123")` is a function-style case expression which has a type (`::std::string`), a value category (prvalue) and a value.

Answer (score 4):

So `string("abc")` ends up calling string's constructor. In this case this "returns" (quotation marks important here, constructors don't technically return anything) a value of type string.

Now, there are multiple types of values, in this case I'd like to distinguish between l-values and r-values. And I'll do so by example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string& s) { std::cout << "l-value reference" << std::endl; }
void foo(std::string&& s) { std::cout << "r-value reference" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string s;
    foo(s);
    foo(std::string());

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/iVhYmg), this prints the following:

```
l-value reference
r-value reference
```

The difference is, that the second string, is a temporary object, and thus an r-value and so the overload taking an r-value reference is called.

So the point I'm trying to make is that both the temporary and non-temporary strings are well, strings. The difference is only that one is temporary and the other is not. Consequently, it is possible to distinguish between l-values and r-values, by for example using overloads for l-value reference and r-value reference.

For an explanation of the differences between value types refer to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Comment: There's an implicit call to `std::string`'s constructor but `string("abc")` is a function-style cast expression. `string` here names the type. I wouldn't say that `string("abc")` is "obviously" a call to string's constructor.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thanks for pointing that out, reworded for clarity

Answer (score 0):

It returns a reference to the constructed object in memory, on which you are calling `size()` method.