# Does constructor return anything?

Tags: c++

Consider this:

```
class A {
  public:
    static A test(){
      return A::A();
    }
};

void main(){
  A a = A::test();
}
```

And it compiles!

UPDATE NO.ONE

Ok, now let's edit this code a bit:

```
class A {
  public:
    static int test(){
      return A::A();
    }
};

void main(){
  int a = A::test();
}
```

Does not compile and here is the error

> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'A' to 'int'

I was taught all my life, that a constructor returns nothing! And it seems now, that it actually returns an object. I am completely blown away, please explain me, what is happening here

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this code shows the constructor returns something?

Comment: Not the constructor, but static method `MyClass::test` returns an object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17938876/5358284

Comment: Whatever constructor returns, it is successfully converted (is conversion even needed here?) to an object of MyClass ...

Comment: @lisyarus What is that static method doing?

Comment: Insert this code: `operator int() const {return 0;}` inside your class and it will compile again. This is called conversion operator. What you are trying to do is converting `MyClass` to `int` in your second example. By the way, main does not return `void`, it returns `int`

Comment: Update your IDE, mate. `void main();` will work perfectly well to you after that. And I do not want to convert my object to int. All I want is to understand, what A::A() constructor returns

Comment: @user3600124 You should update yours. [`main` should return `int` (`void` is even explicitely prohibited)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/4538344) and you can't call a constructor directly.

Answer (score 1):

`return MyClass();` is not a call to a constructor. Firstly, because that method is `static` and constructors are not, you won't be able to call it without providing an instance. Secondly, you can't call a constructor directly.

`MyClass()` creates a temporary variable of type `MyClass` (which implicitly calls a constructor). You can call the same code outside of `MyClass`.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that, but I have corrected my topic a bit. Made an explicit call to the constructor. Still compiles

Comment: It does on my Visual Studio 2013... not there though. `void main();` doesn't work there either

Comment: @user3600124 If Visual Studio does allow calling constructor directly (which is not allowed by ISO C++), it can also return some non-standard value.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a constructor has an evaluation type of the class it resides in and requires no `return` statement. It's simply called by specifying the type and parameters in parentheses (e.g., `MyClass()`). That said, many languages have 'named constructors' and this pattern can be implemented in C++ using a `static` member function that *`return`s* a new instance - and thus has an evaluation type of the enclosing class. This is what we observe here: `MyClass::test()` is a named constructor. It's not *strictly* a constructor by language grammar, since it has to call another constructor in the implementation; but it's a constructor in the sense that it returns a new instance of the class.